# How to code a superclass in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there to code a superclass in sql oracle or would you code it as a normal class?

this is a part of my er diagram of my super class:

[image]

*Sorry, I'm a beginner with sql

Comment: there are no classes in oracle, afaik. You might implement some kind of inheritance through sql but that's a different subject: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0620__Object-Oriented/TypeInheritance.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362994/how-to-call-an-oracle-pl-sql-object-super-method/9364571#9364571

Comment: Classes are called 'types' in Oracle. You can define your own types and then make tables instances of those types.

Comment: Are you talking about persistence - i.e. tables - or programs (procedures. functions)?

Answer (score 1):

There exist several different approaches for this:

1. store all data in a single table (this table has columns for all parent and child attributes)
2. use one table per leaf class, store all attributes in this table (no common table)
3. use one table per class, store only class-specific attributes in this table (use a common table for the base class data, and add FK references to this table in your detail tables)

I'd recommend you grab a copy of [Patterns of Enterprise Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) - it contains exhaustive information on how to handle situations like this.